# .NET PropertyInfo.SetValue seemingly ignoring my commands

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, propertyinfo, setvalue

As the topic suggests I have some problems with PropertyInfo.SetValue. To get to the point, here is my example - I have created my own class and the main thing about it is the presentation object:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestingSetValue
{
public class Link
{
    private object presentationObject = null;
    private string captionInternal = string.Empty;

    public Link (string caption)
    {
        captionInternal = caption;
    }

    public string CaptionInternal
    {
        get { return captionInternal; }
        set { captionInternal = value; }
    }

    public bool Visible
    {
        get 
        {
            if (PresentationObject != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = PresentationObject.GetType().GetProperty("Visible");

                if (pi != null)
                {
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(pi.GetValue(PresentationObject, null));
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        set
        {
            if (PresentationObject != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = PresentationObject.GetType().GetProperty("Visible");

                if (pi != null)
                {
                    pi.SetValue(PresentationObject, (bool)value, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public object PresentationObject
    {
        get { return presentationObject; }
        set { presentationObject = value; }
    }

}
```

}

Then, I do this:

```
private void btnShowLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Link link = new Link("Here I am!");

        this.contextMenu.Items.Clear();
        this.contextMenu.Items.Add(link.CaptionInternal);

        link.PresentationObject = this.contextMenu.Items[0];
        link.Visible = true;

        lblCurrentVisibility.Text = link.Visible.ToString();
    }
```

Now, I can imagine this doesn't look too logical/ economical, but it shows the essence of my real problem. Namely, why doesn't the visibility of presentation object (and the value of link.Visible) change, after I call:

```
link.Visible = true;
```

I simply do not know what else to do to make this work... Any help is deeply appreciated.

To make things even more interesting, the property Enabled behaves as expected of it...

```
PropertyInfo pi = PresentationObject.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled");
```

Could it be related to the fact that Visible is actually a property of ToolStripDropDownItem base base object, whereas Enabled is 'direct' property of ToolStripDropDownItem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been easier to figure this out if you said upfront what class this is but now we know it is ToolStripDropDownItem which we can infer means WinForms.

What you are seeing is an oddity with the ToolStripItem's Visible property.  It's setter & getter are not tied directly together.  MSDN says

> "The Available property is different from the Visible property in that
>   Available indicates whether the ToolStripItem is shown, while Visible
>   indicates whether the ToolStripItem and its parent are shown. Setting
>   either Available or Visible to true or false sets the other property
>   to true or false."

In other words, you want to use the Available property instead of the Visible property

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks so much! I just changed "Visible" to "Available" and now everything works- oh, the joy :) Now, seriously what keyword did you search for to find this, khm, interesting information/ concept?

Comment: @NETFrameworkEnthusiast - I went to the MSDN page for the definition of the ToolStripItem.Visible property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.visible.aspx and saw the comment at the very bottom.  I also looked at this property in Reflector to see that it wasn't implemented in a standard symetrical fashion

Answer (score 1):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx. Maybe this is causing your problem.

There is very important piece of info:

> If this property is false, the server control is not rendered. You should take this into account when organizing the layout of your page. If a container control is not rendered, any controls that it contains will not be rendered even if you set the Visible property of an individual control to true. In that case, the individual control returns false for the Visible property even if you have explicitly set it to true. (That is, **if the Visible property of the parent control is set to false, the child control inherits that setting and the setting takes precedence over any local setting**.)

Comment: Thanks, but we are not dealing with Web control here. It is good old ToolStripDropDownItem and I don't think that the article is relevant for it...

Comment: To make things even more interesting, the property Enabled behaves as expected of it...

    PropertyInfo pi = PresentationObject.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled");

Could it be related to the fact that Visible is actually a property of ToolStripDropDownItem base base object, whereas Enabled is 'direct' property of ToolStripDropDownItem ?